# How to parameterize radio buttons in Loadrunner

Tags: parameters, radio-button, loadrunner

I am working with Loadrunner 12.53. I am recording one simple application which is having two screens in first screen i will enter some value and click on Continue then it will go to second screen where i have almost 25-30 radio buttons all these buttons are vary with the value which i gave in first screen.

I have to make the script working for all the values.

Could you please tell me how to parameterize radio buttons.

Sample response of one of the radio button:
id="TestResponseRequired" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
id="TestResponseRequired_0" type="radio" name="TestResponseRequired" value="1" checked="checked"   for="TestResponseRequired_0">YesNo

Comment: what is the protocol that you have used in recording the application and what's your application technology?

Comment: I am using HTTP protocol and application technology .NET

Comment: assuming its a browser based application, have you tried to parameterize "value","id", "for" and "checked"? it might really help if you could paste a couple of more sample responses for other radio buttons as well

Answer (score 0):

Record several different passes with different options on the radio buttons.  It should become obvious the form data which is being built and how to modify the code to incorporate selection of the buttons.

If you have a variable number of elements in the request, such as only the positively selected radio buttons being selected, then you are likely going to need to head to ther web_custom_request() route.  The use of WCR will allow you to build your own string of name|value pairs which correspond to the values of the selected and unselected in your business case.

Keep in mind that your HTTP test code is operating at a different layer of the OSI than your GUI.  So, you should not expect a GUI identification and selection model akin to functional testing tools which operate against the GUI directly.